# Menu Navigation CSS on Width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have problem with my menu list width, they have different width. What should I do to set larger width for all them?
I downloaded the plugin [here](http://adnantopal.github.io/slimmenu/)

Live demo here : [live demo](http://bloodmyst.com/)

```
.menu-collapser {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #999;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
}
.collapse-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #0E0E0E;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #151515, #040404);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
    padding: 7px 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;

    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
}
.collapse-button:hover, .collapse-button:focus {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #040404;
    color: #FFF;
}
.collapse-button .icon-bar {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 18px;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

ul.slimmenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.slimmenu li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #AAA;
}
ul.slimmenu > li { margin-right: -5px; border-left: 1px solid #999 }
ul.slimmenu > li:first-child { border-left: 0 }
ul.slimmenu > li:last-child { margin-right: 0 }
ul.slimmenu li a {
    max-width: 250px;
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    padding: 12px 64px 12px 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}
ul.slimmenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.slimmenu li .sub-collapser {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 48px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.slimmenu li .sub-collapser:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
}
ul.slimmenu li .sub-collapser > i {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.slimmenu li ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.slimmenu li ul li { background-color: #BBB }
ul.slimmenu li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.slimmenu li > ul > li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.slimmenu.collapsed li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
}
ul.slimmenu.collapsed li a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
}
ul.slimmenu.collapsed li .sub-collapser {
    height: 40px;
}
ul.slimmenu.collapsed li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: static;
}
```

If you need more details, please let me know.

Comment: You can set the min-width of the LIs to the width of the largest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a width for them

You already have a rule (*line 500 of style.css file*), just add the width property

```
ul.slimmenu li {
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; /*ADD THIS LINE*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul.slimmenu li ul li {
   background-color: #BBB;
   width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting width, use the natural behaviour of block elements.

Add `display: block` here:

```
ul.slimmenu li ul li { background-color: #BBB; display: block; }
```

The parent element (ul) is set to be a block one. By setting its children (li) to `display: block` - you naturally "tell" them to take full width of their parent.